# URL in revealing footer not working on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index

The button in my footer is not working in IE. I think this has sonething to do with z-index. It is currently set to -1 on the footer and 1 on main-content. I have searched stack overflow and see many posts about z-index and IE. Could this be the case here aswell?
[Link to website](https://littlemighty.dk). The two css classes look like this:

```
.main-content {
  background: #f5f2eb;
  background: var(--background, #f5f2eb);
  min-height:0vh;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index:1;
 } 

footer {
  padding-top: 100px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:380px;
  background: rgb(255, 115, 50);
  background: var(--footer, rgb(255, 115, 50));
  color:#fff;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. You need to show the minimal code that reproduces the issue directly inside your question.https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: I tried to check the site and it looks like the issue is related to Z-index. If possible then try to provide a simple sample that can help us to produce the issue. We can make some tests with it to see whether there is any way to fix it. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I tried to run your code.I hit the button as if something was blocking it in the website.

I think it should be the Z-index level problem.The outermost Z-index is limited by IE. no matter how high the inner Z-index is, it can't surpass the outer.

You could try to separate each level in body, like the following:

```css
<style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0;}
    .contain{width:300px;height:300px;margin:50px;color:#fff;background:#609;position:relative;}
    .box1{width:100px;height:100px;background:#FC0;position:absolute;top:200px;left:100px;z-index:20;}
    .box2{width:100%;height:100%;background:#ccc;opacity:0.6;filter:Alpha(opacity=60);position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:10;}
    </style>
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="contain">Parent (first level)</div>
    <div class="box1">Top pop up (third level)</div>
    <div class="box2">Transparent overlay (second level)</div>
    
      <!--  <div class="contain">Parent (first level)  
           <div class="box1">Top pop up (third level)</div>
        </div>

        <div class="box2">Transparent overlay (second level)</div>
--> 
        


</body>
```

In addition, you could also try to check your [relevant IE settings](https://www.genopro.com/help/report-generator/allow-blocked-content/).